# why is json.net only showing s#arp EntityWithTypedId class?

Tags: c#, json.net, s#arp-architecture

I'm using an older version of Sharp arch on a project and I'm trying to serialize using JSON.NET.  JavascriptSerializer works, but I prefer JSON.NET for the preferences.

Here's the problem.  For some reason, when I try to serialize a simple Sharp object I get the following:

```
// my sharp object
[Serializable]
public class Contact : Entity
{
    public virtual string EmailAddress { get; set; }
}

...

// in sharp, this is what happens to Entity
[Serializable]
public abstract class Entity : EntityWithTypedId<int> {
    protected Entity();
}

// and then into EntityWithTypedId
[Serializable]
public abstract class EntityWithTypedId<IdT> : ValidatableObject, IEntityWithTypedId<IdT> {
    protected EntityWithTypedId();

    [JsonProperty]
    [XmlIgnore]
    public virtual IdT Id { get; protected set; }

    public override bool Equals(object obj);
    public override int GetHashCode();
    protected override IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> GetTypeSpecificSignatureProperties();
    public virtual bool IsTransient();
}
```

When I run the following JSON convert, I only get back `{ "Id" : 0 }` as a result.

```
Contact test = new Contact {
    EmailAddress = "test@test.com"
};
string result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(test);
```

Any ideas on how to return the entire object contents?

Comment: Just [tested](https://github.com/seif/Sharp-Architecture/commit/c1757af64c19465e930b2c8f92e2b8ecbcce3a1d) exactly what you have given with the latest version of sharp architecture and the object was correctly serialized, what version of SharpArchitecture/Newtonsoft.Json are you using?

Comment: Hi Attar, currently we have to stick with SharpArch.dll v1.6.0.0.  And latest version of Newtonsoft.Json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The BaseObject class in S#arp Architecture had member serialisation set to OptIn, which has been removed in 2.0.

Your options are:

- Update to Sharp Architecture 2.0
- Use a different json serialiser, [ServiceStack.Text](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text) is great.
- Recompile Sharp Architecture 1.6 with the property removed
- Add JsonProperty attribute to specific properties you want serialised

Comment: Thanks for the help, I ended up reverting to JSON.NET 3.5.  I'll definitely take a look at ServiceStack.Text as recommended.  For some reason recompiling also slipped my mind :)